# What's the difference between Spring Integration using XML vs Java DSL?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

What are the advantages of Spring Integration using XML over using Java DSL?
I find that all docs are written using XML declarative format, however, I personally find it easier to write Java code rather than XML. Is there any reason for reconsidering my view point?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "difference" at runtime; only XML was available originally; we are adding more DSL examples to the docs/samples over time. e.g. https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/sftp.html#configuring-with-the-java-dsl

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class SftpJavaApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SpringApplicationBuilder(SftpJavaApplication.class)
            .web(false)
            .run(args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow sftpInboundFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Sftp.inboundAdapter(this.sftpSessionFactory)
                    .preserveTimestamp(true)
                    .remoteDirectory("foo")
                    .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                    .localFilenameExpression("#this.toUpperCase() + '.a'")
                    .localDirectory(new File("sftp-inbound")),
                 e -> e.id("sftpInboundAdapter")
                    .autoStartup(true)
                    .poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(5000)))
            .handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload()))
            .get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @GaryRussell. I understand that there is no difference in runtime. But, I read somewhere that DSL is only in maintenance mode. Is that correct? What is better to use in your opinion?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "maintenence" mode. Both methods of configuration are actively supported. "Better" is subjective; if you prefer DSL then use it.

Comment: You may be referring to the stand-alone DSL project (used with the framework 4.3.x version). The DSL was brought into the core project staring with version 5.0. The current version is 5.2.

Comment: Thanks, @GaryRussell. That answers my question.